Is the following problem a matroid?
Most, if not all, of the examples for matroids and greedoids are either graph or linear algebra oriented, so I'm struggling to see if unrelated problems are or are not matroids/greedoids. I have the following greedy problem.
Problem:
Given a set of numbers in the real line $x_1 \leq x_2 \leq \ldots \leq x_n$ determine the smallest set of unit length closed interval that contain all of the given points.
I know the greedy solution is to take the intervals $[x_i, x_i +1]$ iterate in increasing order while adding them to our solution set until we have covered all $x_i$. You can prove that this is the best solution compared to any other, but I can't see how can I get an independent set (if possible) out of this.

For a problem to be a matroid, it needs a ground set. Here it seems that the ground set is infinite, however matroids require finite ground sets.

One can define infinite matroids (see Axioms for infinite matroids by Bruhn et. al).
The motivation that I believe you have here is that an independence system, that is, as non-empty set system (on a finite groundset) closed under subsets, is a matroid if and only if the greedy algorithm outputs a maximally independent set of minimal cost for every nonnegative cost function on the groundset. What is meant by the greedy algorithm here is an algorithm that starts with the empty set, and iteratively adds elements to this set while maintaining independence.
It seems to me here that you would like the groundset to consist of unit intervals in $\mathbb{R}$. However, I don't believe you have an independence system.
